# When $n$ is odd, $\langle (123),(12...n)\rangle$ generates $A_{n}$

Tags: group-theory

Working with the knowledge that the set of 3-cycles generates $A_{n}$, the basic idea is to express any 3-cycle as a word in $(123)$ and $(12...n)$ when $n$ is odd.

Not knowing how to progress, I decided to work with the concrete group $A_{5}$. I've listed all 3-cycles of $A_{5}$ below with each element followed by its inverse: $$(123),(132),(124),(142),(125),(152),(134),(143),(135),(153),(145),(154),(234),(243),(235),(253),(245),(254),(345),(354)$$ Now, I am able to generate the following elements $(234),(345),(451),(512)$ (and, correspondingly, their inverses) using the following rule:$$(12345)^{i}(123)(12345)^{-i}$$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ (for $i=5$ we get back $(123)$).

Promising as this looks, I am not able to extend the idea to cover the other 3-cycles in $A_{5}$.

Suggestions and hints are appreciated. Would prefer to answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here it goes. I went back to the book (Groups & Symmetry by M.A. Armstrong) and used one of the results in a proof (Theorem 6.5) from there, namely that $A_{n}$ can be generated by 3-cycles of the form $(1ab)$.

Here is the idea. Based on @Michael Albanese's writing of 3-cycles of the form $(a\space a+1\space a+2)$ as words in $(123)$ and $(12...n)$, showing that the 3-cycles of the form $(a\space a+1\space a+2)$ generate $A_{n}$ proves that $\langle{(123),(12...n)}\rangle = A_{n}$.

Observe the following: $$(134)=(234)(123)(234)^{-1}$$ $$(145)=(345)(234)(123)(234)^{-1}(345)^{-1}$$ $$(156)=(456)(345)(234)(123)(234)^{-1}(345)^{-1}(456)^{-1}$$ In general, for $a>1$, $$(1\space a\space a+1)=(a-1\space a\space a+1)(a-2\space a-1\space a)\cdots(234)(123)(234)^{-1}\cdots(a-1\space a\space a+1)^{-1}$$ So now we have to show that all 3-cycles of the form $(1\space a\space a+1)$ generate $A_{n}$.

Here is where I use the result from the book: all cycles of the form $(1ab)$ generate $A_{n}$. Notice that $(1\space a+1 \space a+2)(1\space a \space a+1)=(1\space a \space a+2)$. For $b>a$, this can be generalized as follows: $$(1ab)=(1\space b-1 \space b)(1\space b-2 \space b-1)\cdots(1\space a+1\space a+2)(1\space a\space a+1)$$ And of $b<a$, we simply use the relation $(1ab)=(1ba)^{2}$ with the above. Hence, all 3-cycles of the form $(1\space a\space a+1)$ generate $A_{n}$.

Comment: If anybody can take a look at the solution above, it would be much appreciated. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

\begin{align*}
(1\ 2\ \dots\ n)(1\ 2\ 3)(1\ 2\ \dots\ n)^{-1} &= (2\ 3\ 4)\\
(1\ 2\ \dots\ n)(2\ 3\ 4)(1\ 2\ \dots\ n)^{-1} &= (3\ 4\ 5)\\
&\ \ \vdots
\end{align*}

More generally, given a permutation $\sigma$ and a cycle $(a_1\ a_2\ \dots\ a_k)$, we have

$$\sigma(a_1\ a_2\ \dots\ a_k)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1)\ \sigma(a_2)\ \dots\ \sigma(a_k)).$$

Finally, use the fact that $(a\ b\ c)^{-1} = (a\ c\ b)$.

Comment: I'm worried because this seems to work for any $n$, not just $n$ odd.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese If $n$ is even, then $(1 2 \ldots n) \notin A_n$.

Comment: @Sfarla: Thanks! That was pretty stupid of me.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Using your general notation how would you write the element (124) in $A_{5}$?

Comment: As $(5\ 1\ 2)(4\ 5\ 1)(5\ 1\ 2)^{-1}$. I haven't written all the details as you wanted hints.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But how did you know how to choose (512) for $\sigma$ and the permutation (451) to be in the middle?

Comment: Well, I chose one of the numbers in the cycle $(1\ 2\ 4)$, in this case $4$, then started with one of the cycles that are of the 'consecutive' form in my answer, in this case $(4\ 5\ 1)$. Then I chose a $3$-cycle that would send $5$ to $1$ but fix $4$, in this case $(5\ 1\ 2)$. In this case, I was lucky because once $5$ was sent to $1$, the initial $1$ became a $2$ then I was done. In general, I'd have to do more work than this. Let me know if you want me to add more details to my answer.

Comment: Ok. I took a different approach, but I used your idea. Thanks again for your help!